# The same code works in Mathematica but not in Matlab

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I have a problem with the code I post below. From this code I know what to expect: I need to have only one (positive) eigenvalue equal to one and the quantity I name qfi must be equal to 4 no matter what the value of a is (as the value of a increases I must increase the number of modes to get the correct result, but this is expected. And it's not that but, for example if I have a=10 with 150 modes  get qfi 3.99986 which is ok).

This code runs perfectly in Mathematica. The thing is that I need to write something more complicated than that and I don't know how to use mathematica properly, so I want to use matlab.  But in Matlab it doesn't work at all, even in cases where everything is well defined (because if I increase the number of modes in Matlab I get a NaN in the matrices). For example, for a=2 for modes=100 (which is a good number of modes) i get qfi 80.0000.

So, I post the two codes, if any of you can find a mistake. I guess it has to do with precision, but what I found online about increasing precision mentioned the symbolic toolbox. Is there something else i could do?

I'm sorry for posting the whole code, but I'm struggling with it for days.

Mathematica code: (it's not very well copied)

```
modes = 100;

a = 2;

neg = 0;

(* the (l,m) element of the matrix *)

g[l_, m_] := (a^(l + m) E^-a^2)/Sqrt[Factorial[l]*Factorial[m]]

ρ = N[Table[g[l, m], {l, 0, modes}, {m, 0, modes}]];

tr = Tr[ρ]

ρnorm = ρ*(1/tr);

(*I find the eigenvalues and vectors. We want 1 eigenvalue equal to 1 and 
  all the others 0 *)

eige = Eigenvalues[ρnorm];

eige = Chop[eige];

vec = Eigenvectors[ρnorm];

vec = Chop[vec];

For[i = 0, i <= modes, i++, x = eige[[i]]; If[x < 0, neg = neg + 1]];

neg

0

Length[eige] - Count[eige, 0]

1

Max[eige]

1.

(* A second matrix like the first one *)

deriv[k_, n_] := (a^(-1 + k + n) E^-a^2 (-2 a^2 + k + n))/ Sqrt[k! n!]

derρ = N[Table[deriv[k, n], {k, 0, modes}, {n, 0, modes}]];

derρ = Chop[derρ];

L = 0;

For[i = 0, i <= modes, i++;
 For[j = 0, j <= modes , modes, j++;
   If[eige[[i]] + eige[[j]] != 0,
    (*I multiply eigenvectors with the derρ matrix *)
    rd = vec[[i]].derρ.tra[vec[[j]]];
    rd = Chop[rd];
    rd = rd[[1]];

    (*I multiply an eigenvector with the transpose of an other one and \
         I create the L matrix *)
    L = L + rd/(eige[[i]] + eige[[j]])*tra[vec[[i]]].{vec[[j]]}
    ]]]


    L = 2*L;
    L = Chop[L];

    qfi = Tr[ρnorm.L.L]

    4.
```

MatLab code (rhodiff=derρ):

```
modes=100;
acc=1e-15;
a=2;
rho=zeros(modes,modes);
rhodiff=zeros(modes,modes);

for l=1:modes
    for m=1:modes
    rho(l,m)=(a^(l+m-2))*exp(-a^2)/(sqrt(factorial(l-1)*factorial(m-1)));
    end
end

tr=trace(rho);
rhonorm=rho/tr;

[V,D]=eig(rhonorm);
D(abs(D)<acc)=0;

for l=1:modes
    for m=1:modes
    rhodiff(l,m)=(a^(l+m-1))*(-2*a^2+l+m)*exp(-a^2)/(sqrt(factorial(l-1)*factorial(m-1)));
    end
 end

 L=zeros(modes,modes);

 for i=1:modes
    for j=1:modes
        if D(i,i)+D(j,j)~=0
        rd=((V(:,i)')*rhodiff*V(:,j));   
        rd(abs(rd)<acc)=0; 

        L=L+(((rd/(D(i,i)+D(j,j))))*V(:,i)*V(:,j)');
        L(abs(L)<acc)=0;
        end
    end
end

L=2*L;
qfi=trace(rhonorm*L*L)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is almost definitely due to precision. In Matlab, the default is double precision. In your code, at one point, you are computing `factorial(modes-1)*factorial(modes-1)`. That is a very large number.

In Matlab, the representation of that number will be limited to double precision. In Mathematica, since it is an integer, my guess is that it can represent that number precisely.

The best course of action is to make your computation more numerically stable. The best way to do that is to turn expressions of the form

`(a^(l+m-2))*exp(-a^2)/(sqrt(factorial(l-1)*factorial(m-1)))`

into products so that you never have to actually have some really large number in memory. For instance, it seems that the above expression can be equivalently written as

`exp(-a^2) * prod( a ./ sqrt(1:l-1) ) * prod( a ./ sqrt(1:m-1) )`

this version never asks you to compute something like `factorial(100)`, which cannot be represented precisely in double precision.

I haven't checked it, but it looks like your other expression

`(a^(l+m-1))*(-2*a^2+l+m)*exp(-a^2)/(sqrt(factorial(l-1)*factorial(m-1)))`

could be written as

`(-2*a^2+l+m)*a*exp(-a^2) * prod( a ./ sqrt(1:l-1) ) * prod( a ./ sqrt(1:m-1) )`

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped to one part. Now I'm getting the correct eigenvalues for my matrix and as I increase the number of modes I don't get the NaN error anymore. So thanks, because I would never have thought of that. However, it still doesn't work. I compared them and the code differs after it calculates L. So, I was thinking, could it be the way the two of them calculate the eigenvectors?

Comment: Please compare the output for a fixed value of 'a' and 'modes'. At which line in the Matlab code does it differ from the similar line in mathematica?

Comment: Ok, so: the rhonorm/ρnorm matrix is the same, Eigenvalues the same, eigenvectors different: in mathematica all the eigenvectors are real and in matlab they are complex with the complex part of the same order of magnitude are the real part in some cases. rhodiff/derρ (they are evaluated independently) are the same. And then L is different. In matlab L is just a matrix with all elements 1 multiplied by a constant, which is not correct. So the differences are the eigenvectors and L (which depends on them). (Again thank you for the help)

Comment: But there is another issue I haven't written and just occurred to me. The eigenvectors that are different are the ones with zero eigenvalues. So, could it be that the eigenvectors of mathematica happen to work for my case?

Comment: It is possible. It could be that you are relying on how the eigenvectors are generated. This can be ambiguous. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector

Comment: Ok, I'll check it. Thank you very much!